# Run Delayed Job at a specific time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, delayed-job

I have a email delivery job which I would like to run at the user specified time. I have a datetime column deliver_at at which I should deliver the emails. I am using delayed-job for performing background jobs.

delayed job alows me to specify the time difference and not the exact time for scheduling the job.

```
  GiftCardMailerJob.set(wait: delay_by.minutes.from_now).perform_later(go)
```

Is there a way I give the deliver_at time directly and make delayed job run at that time?

If not how can I arrive at the time difference?

```
((deliver_at - Time.now) / 60).minutes.from_now
```

Should be the correct approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `enqueue` method in `delayed_jobs`

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue(GiftCardMailerJob.new, :run_at => deliver_at)
```

If you see the `delayed_jobs` table in the database, the `run_at` field is of type `datetime` and you can have any `datetime` value for it.